# Pandas groupby Id and count occurrences of picklist/unique values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a table that looks like this:
[image]

I would like to count how many times each company has raised capital and count the funding types. Ideally, the output table would look like this:

```
company id | Equity | Debt | Private Placement
1          |     2  |   3  |       0
2          |     0  |   1  |       2
```

Is there a way to do this with pandas? I've tried different variations of groupby, count, and transpose but nothing has worked for me.

Comment: Yes, of course there is a way. But please, don't paste images of code or data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df.groupby(['company id', 'funding_type']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
```